# Launch using Dedicated Graphics Card, can we add extra Graphic card for better performence

Tags: 20.04, graphics, lenovo, laptop

[image]

**i want to increase my laptop speed
so can i add externally graphic card.**

my laptop -> lenovo W530

Comment: Lenovo W530 already has a dedicated GPU (Nvidia).

Comment: but i want one more graphic Card (externally)

Comment: If you want to spend a small fortune for no appreciable performance gain (depending on the actual eGPU) and an hell of headaches just for setting it up and managing drivers: https://gamerslens.com/best-external-graphics-card-for-laptop-egpu/

Answer (score 0):

Your title, as well as your clarifying comment seem to make it clear that you want a performance increase by running *two* GPUs simultaneously -- The discrete GPU in your laptop coupled with an external GPU.

In that case, the answer is *no*.  While there are technologies that allow two GPUs to be coupled (e.g. nVidia SLI), these are (were) limited to using the identical GPU in two PCIe slots.  You can't use it to couple the internal GPU with an external one since there's no shared bus.

You *can* add a Thunderbolt eGPU which would almost certainly outperform the internal one, but it's probably not worth it.  You'd be better off building a desktop system with a stronger GPU (if you can find one in stock currently).  The price/performance would likely be better for the desktop system, and it's not like the eGPU option is all that "laptopable" anyway.